# Grouping in CouchDb

Tags: couchdb

I have a couchdb database where each document is an email :

```
{
   "_id": "8e7a440862347a22f4a1b2ca7f000e83",
   "type": "email",
   "sender": "dexter@gmail.com",
   "subject": "Hello",
   "content":"..."
}
```

I'd like to build a view where I see all the emails sent by a user. A user can have multiple email addresses.

A user could be defined like this (but please tell me any better way):

```
{
   "_id":"hsuehdiqj28jej83",
   "type": "user",
   "emails": ["dexter@gmail.com","dexter.2@gmail.com"]
}
```

Since there is a lot of email, I'd like not to store the user in the email document. I'd like to be able to change any user email list easily.

Do you have any idea how to do ?

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to have a view keyed on `sender` that you could then query with a list of keys that match a particular user, but you can't create a view that groups all emails for a user without having the user id in the email document.